# This SQL Statement won't work with AND operator

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, select

I have run the following query and print_r() it:

```
$query = "SELECT TemplateID, UserId FROM database WHERE UserId = '598'";
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Then I run the following query and print_r() it:

```
$query = "SELECT TemplateID, UserId FROM database WHERE TemplateID = '5160';
```

Here is the result:

[image]

For some reason, the following statement wouldn't work, and just return empty:

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE UserId = '598' AND TemplateID = '5160'
```

Please help me point out where I did wrong. I've been stuck with this for hours. By concept, I believe the third statement should work. I also checked my syntax and spelling, and I couldn't seem to find a reason for it.

Comment: There is no user id that is `test` it is `tester` if you need to find all users where LIKE test than check this link: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: You have a typo in the third statement `TempalteID`

Comment: there may be no rows in the table matching these conditions

Comment: I'm so sorry for the spellings. I have corrected my spelling. The first statement works, and the second statement works, so why wouldn't the last one work? The last one is only the combination of both statements.

Comment: `UserId = 'test'` this should be tester

Comment: try a 'union' of both of your statements and you should get a result

Comment: @cuzmAZN . . . Because they return different rows.  They may happen to look very similar, but they are different rows.

Comment: Are you saying it still fails after removing your typos?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Hi. I used print_r() to view and I'm quite positive there is one row that contains both 'tester' and '1111111111'. There is also only 1 table.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM database WHERE UserId = 'tester' union SELECT * FROM database WHERE TemplateID = '1111111111'` - what result does this give? Or just change AND to OR - `SELECT * FROM database WHERE UserId = 'tester' OR TemplateID = '1111111111'` - does this give 2 rows?

Comment: @OIS: Yes. The this is a pseudo code so the spelling won't matter. I checked really carefully my project and I did copy/paste, manually type... to make sure there is no typos. The last statement just won't work.

Comment: The SQL shown *will* work with the data shown. Thus it is a problem with the data entry of such.There is *nothing* with 'AND' that will make either of the conditions false: they (one or both) *must* be false on their own, or else the single expected row would be returned. Since this disagrees with the reported results then either the result (or data shown) is misrepresented or the conditions vary between statements (ie. one contains a non-break space; retype it from scratch to avoid this possibility).

Comment: Are you sure you are using the table name where it now says `database`? The query is good, if all data matches.

Comment: works just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6094c/1/0

Comment: @OIS Why would that be needed or help in the slightest? 'tester' and '1111111111' are in *the same reported data row*.

Comment: @OIS: It returns all rows with UserId = 'tester' and all rows with TemplateID = '1111111111'.

Comment: @user2864740 just run both queries please - this is called debugging.

Comment: ah, more then one, you didn't mention that ... - well, the query should work if there is a row with both those values. - I suggest you create a new table like the original, copy over the one row you want to find. see if both the 2 original queries match.

Comment: I have uploaded again my code with the screenshot. Please advise..

Comment: remove the single quotes

Comment: @JamieD77: I have tested it with and without the single quotes. Even with the single quote, the query would run if there is no "AND" in it. That's the weird thing. If I run both statement independently, they would all work. But when I combine them with "AND," they just show empty space.

Comment: try with `SELECT * FROM database WHERE TemplateID = '5160'` what do you see. Im pretty sure you made a silly mistake

Comment: Have you tried in the database:  `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM database WHERE UserId = '598' AND TemplateID = '5160'; SHOW WARNINGS\G`?

Comment: @meda: I have updated my question with the query given. When select rows by TemplateID, it returns all rows with those TemplateID. I don't see any thing wrong with my statement. Even the row with UserId = '598' is there.

Comment: @OIS: I added "EXPLAIN EXTENDED" to my query as suggested. I'm using PHP, and the server is MSSQL (I don't know if it matters). PHP will throw error and won't let the query run.

Comment: Removed MySQL tag since latest comment here says this is MSSQL

Comment: Downvoted for changing the data so much. You provided a blatantly misleading 'SSCCE' - so much so that the final changes don't even relate to 'the problem'. See my comment above (tldr; PEBCAK). I have no idea if it is any less incorrect after substituting in the pictures; nor do I care to squint my eyes or participate any more in a string of conjecture.

Comment: @cuzmAZN you have to run it while connected to the db with a client, not from PHP. explain extended might not work on mssql, so try just explain.

Comment: Try this and tell us what you get for the row(s) you think should be returned when using AND...  `SELECT CASE WHEN UserID = 598 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CASE WHEN TemplateID = 5160 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, UserID, TemplateID FROM database WHERE UserID = 598 OR TemplateID = 5160 ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2 DESC`

Comment: @OIS This is called "a bunch of useless conjecture not supported by the current - whatever that; and how misleading that; really is - input conditions and results". As per my previous comments, at the time when written, this "debugging" (and your comment) was both *useless and erroneous*. If the data (or relevance of your previous comment) has changed before or since that point that is not my concern.

Comment: @MatBailie: Hi Mat. This is really interesting. I can't seem to find any row that contain both UserId 598 and TempalteID 5160. So does it mean something? If such row doesn't exist, why does my first screenshot show that they exist (top row)?

Comment: Either your data changed underneath you, or your test was faulty.  As others have said, try these tests in a native sql client rather than your own php application - One by one eliminate all possible points of failure and don't assume anything you wrote works..

Comment: So I have tried the tests in native SQL Client and they work. Now I am left with a question why it wouldn't work using PHP, for the exact same query. Even though I couldn't select the specific row, as asked, I could still update the exact row with PHP. That is so weird.

Answer (score 0):

Your third statement is checking for UserID = 'test', but in the sample data you provided, you only have a record with the UserID = 'tester'.

So your statement won't return anything, because no such row matches both items

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some spaces somewhere in the TemplateID column.  Try

`SELECT * FROM database WHERE UserId = 'tester' AND TemplateID LIKE '%1111111111%'`

Actually check if either field has spaces

```
SELECT * 
FROM   database 
WHERE  UserId LIKE '%tester%' 
       AND TemplateID LIKE '%1111111111%'
```

Remove the single quotes

`SELECT * FROM database WHERE UserId = 598 AND TemplateID = 5160`

Comment: Hi. I have tried the LIKE statement but it won't work. I have uploaded my question again with screenshot. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT TemplateID, UserID FROM database
WHERE TemplateID='5160'
ORDER BY UserID

this query specifying distinct combinations of templateID and userID, may help you check if the combination you want exist in your database

Comment: Hi. I have tried the query you gave me, and the combination I was looking for does exist.

Comment: try the query in a client (cli or gui) while connected to the db. if it doesnt work there, I suggest you delete this, make a new post with just sql and sql-server tags. explain the problem clearly from the get go, with explain table, explain select etc.

Comment: you need to explain what is happening, getting any errors or messages or just a blank output window